# Consulta SQL postgis em tabelas vazias

Tags: postgresql, postgis

em alguns momentos tenho a necessidade de realizar alguma consulta postgresql/postgis em camadas vazias como por exemplo:

```
select st_difference(camada_a.geom, camada_b.geom) as geom from camada_a, camada_b
```

sendo que neste caso a "camada_a" está povoada, enquanto que a "camada_b" é uma tabela vazia.
A consulta acima está me retornando uma camada vazia. Porém, eu esperava que o código me retornasse a "camada_a", já que "camada_b" é vazia, ou seja, eu gostaria que camada_a - camada_b = camada_a, ao invés de camada_a - camada_b = *vazio*

Já notei que sempre ao realizar quaisquer consulta e inserir no fim do código tipo "from 'uma camada vazia'" sempre retornará vazio.

Alguém pode me ajudar a contornar isso?

Comment: Você pode usar o [coalesce](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-coalesce/), `coalesce(camada_b.geom, camada_a.geom)`.

Comment: Testei e não funcionou, me parece que coalesce retorna o primeiro valor não nulo, o que não é o caso, já que a tabela em questão está vazia ao invés de valores null.

Comment: Então você pode usar [case when](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE).

Comment: Nesse caso eu precisaria colocar no fim do código "from" a camada vazia o que também me retorna vazio.